# How to load functualities from another pahe to current page after click <a href="?s=contact&id="

Tags: php, jquery

This is my first page index.php:

```
<body>
  <div id="nerde2"> </div>
   <div id="nerde1"> </div>


   <input type="button" value="ilk update" id="update" />
<!--   <input type="button" value="ilk save" id="save" />-->
   <a href="?s=contact&id=" onClick="functionmert();" class="btn btn-default" id="save">ilk save</a>

<script src="Jquery_Projesi/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Jquery_Projesi/js/js.js"></script>
<script src="get_post.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is my second page index2.php:

```
<body>
   <?php
      if(isset($_GET['savee'])){
          ?>
             <form action="" method="post">
             <input type="submit" value="save">
             <input type="text" name="a">
             </form>
          <?php
      }

    ?>
    <?php
       if(isset($_GET['updatee'])){
           ?>
               <form action="" method="post">
             <input type="submit" value="update">
             <input type="text" name="b">
             </form>
           <?php
       }
    ?>


</body>
```

This is my third page get_post.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   "use strict";

    $('#update').click(function(){
        $('#nerde2').hide(1000);
        $('#nerde1').show(3000);
        var vall="veri gonderildi";
        $.get('index2.php',{updatee:vall},function(data){
            $('#nerde1').html(data);

        });
    });

    $('#save').click(function(){
            $('#nerde1').hide(1000);
            $('#nerde2').show(3000);
            var vall="veri gonderildi";
            $.get('index2.php',{savee:vall},function(data){
            $('#nerde2').html(data);

        });     
    });
});
```

When i click save or update button, i want to show index2.php functions on the index.php page.

I used a get method in jquery.js and everything is working but when i am using an , page is refreshing and nothing appends inside to the index.php

Comment: if you log the data with console.write(data) can you see what you want to insert into nerde1?

Comment: normally when i use the href="?s=contact&id="> as  <a href="#" > , it is working but the main problem is when index.php is refreshing( after clicking ilk save in the index.php ), everything lossing. i used $(windows).bind("load",function(){   jquery.js codes    });  , but again it doesn't work,

Comment: thank you very mush sir , it is working now :)

Comment: Your welcome. Try using just return false, you may not need preventDefault. Please mark my answer as correct if it's solved your issue.

Comment: yes it is working, but i dont see in the adress bar the content of href="?s=contact&id=">  ,  i see the adress bar as  localhost/index.php , only.

Comment: try using                     `window.history.replaceState({path:url},'',url);` or `history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");` to add the url to the browser history/address bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the default event propagation. Try adding the following to your code

```
$('#update').click(function(e){ 

    e.preventDefault(); 

    $('#nerde2').hide(1000); 
    $('#nerde1').show(3000); 

    var vall="veri gonderildi"; 

    $.get('index2.php',{updatee:vall},function(data){ 
        $('#nerde1').html(data); 
    }); 

    return false; 
});
```